# Is it safe to just subscribe to Publishers in the assembly phase and leave it at that?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I've asked in Gitter already but looks like it's not too active these days..

I was curious, is it safe to use such constructs in production code:

```
private Mono<Void> someHandler() {
        someService.registerPlayer(internalPlayer)
                        .subscribe();

        return Mono.empty();
    }
```

and then just use this `Publisher` from WebFlux controller method, for example?

do we have anything in the official documentation about it? All the examples I could find in the Reference, seem to be examples of calling reactive code from blocking code and observing behavior.

I guess this Disposable returned here will be GC-ed quite soon, right?
and what would be the right way to achieve similar result (emitting on the outer `Publisher` without having to wait till the inner `Publisher` completes; but making sure it's completed nevertheless)

Comment: I don't get the point about "without having to wait till the inner Publisher completes; but making sure it's completed nevertheless".  Is it a fire-and-forget scenario or you want to return some result for further processing? And what do you mean by "wait" ?

Comment: it's almost "fire-and-forget" but I want to be _confident_ that the subscription will complete. The presented code is not giving me this confidence, for some reason. by "wait" I mean "complete this Publisher (the one I return from the method) only *after* the other one" - this is a thing I want to avoid. 

In an imperative, blocking code, an analogous construct would be to start some processing on a separate thread and return immediately, without having to wait till that thread is done

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, then it is basically a fire-and-forget scenario, but nothing prevents you from using additional operators on that chain to process the results.

If by *"to beconfident that the subscription will complete"* you mean *"do something if it is completed successfully"* or *"do something if it is completed with error"* then:

If you want to start some processing in a separate thread and return immediately, and also be *confident* in completion of that sepapate processing, then you can use both `subscribeOn()` and put some operators to that chain to handle the results of success or errors of that processing, just as you do when you build any reactive chain.

To handle the results you can use, for example, `.map()`, `doOnNext()`, `flatMap()`, `switchIfEmpty()`, etc., whatever fits your requirements,

To handle errors, you can use, for example, `onErrorResume()`, `onErrorContinue()`, `onErrorMap()`, `onErrorReturn()`, `doOnError()`, etc., whatever fits your requirements.

Here is an example how it would look like:

```java
private Mono<Void> someHandler() {
    someService.registerPlayer(internalPlayer)
            // handle results
            .doOnNext(...)
    
            // handle errors
            .orErrorResume(...)
            // the whole subscription process will happen on the thread provided by the Scheduler you specified
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .subscribe();
    // return immediately
    return Mono.empty();
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what we do; question is - what guarantees do I have that it's safe thing to do? the value returned by `.subscribe()` is not stored anywhere; how can I be confident it's not going to be just removed by the GC with all it's subscriptions etc ? I am struggling to find anything in the official reference regarding this usage of `.subscribe()`

Comment: to be fair: I am quite certain I have used such tricks in the past too; I just started growing uneasy about it and want to find some tangible proof of either argument., whether it's perfectly fine pattern or if there're any implications to keep in mind

Comment: actually there's nothing wrong to subscribe() in such cases somewhere in your application, because what the rule about subscribe() states is: the who is considered to be a consumer, the he should call subscribe(). Since the consumer of your separate process is the application itself (because it is a "background processing"), then there's nothing wrong with that. Also I don't see any problem with garbage collecting, since basically it works when there's no any reference found to an object.

Comment: you mean even if Disposable is garbage-collected, subscription is bound to be completed? not cancelled?

Comment: I think what you should care about is what Scheduler to provide in subscribeOn() in your case. Does your process perform some CPU-bound work? Then use Schedulers.parallel(). Does your process perform IO-operations (blocking/non-blocking)? Then use Schedulers.boundedElastic()

Comment: it would be collected after the thread finished it's work. Since different thread and  it's stack will hold all necessary references.

Comment: so basically you're saying that if we care to use the proper Scheduler for `.subscribeOn()` then such pattern of usage is perfectly fine?

Comment: Right, that's literally what I mean

Comment: Understood; well, that would be my assumption too.. for the most part I created this question in an attempt to get some feedback from Reactor team and eventually have this subject also discussed in the Reference pages.

Comment: Also one point to add: this approach may lead to problem "fast producer - slow consumer" if your separate process is really slow compared to the producer. Since you're losing backpressure benefits "breaking" your reactive chain "in the middle". But it is debatable, because sometimes we really need some background processing of requests from producer.

Comment: I may add from my experience. We have a couple of projects where we use such technique, and I also had some concerns regarding it. But it seems to be working fine so far. GC doesn't touch it until it completes b/c references are still here. And we use `subscribeOn` usually.